# Changes of a json not taken into account NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coming to you because I'm trying to do a foreach loop on Discord.JS to detect changes in a JSON file. My file does change content, but my foreach loop keeps the old content in memory. I have no idea how to solve the problem...

My index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const database = require('./db.json');

const adapter = new FileSync('./db.json')
const db = low(adapter)

const prefix = config.prefix;
let api = config.api;

client.once('ready', () => {
    db.defaults({numbers: []})
    .write()

    setInterval(function() {
    database.numbers.forEach(async element => {
        let state = await fetch(`some-api-url`).then(response => response.json());

        if(state[0].response != element.response){
            db.get('numbers')
            .find({number: element.number})
            .assign({response: state[0].response, sms: state[0].msg})
            .write();
            let user = element.clientId;

            try {
                await client.users.cache.get(user).send(`Your message for number ${element.number} is ${element.sms}`);
                } catch(error){
                 console.log(error)
                }
        }

        });

    }, 3000);

    console.log('Ready!');
});
```

It all works, it just keeps the old file in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I passed my `const database = require('./db.json');` into let. Then I integrated fs so that I could clear the cache:

```
setInterval(function() {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./db.json')]
        database = require('./db.json');
```

Problem solved!